# How to stop/start thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a workerthread that takes a username and password from two inputboxes, but I want to stop it if username/password are blank.

I've tried to use the Suspend() method but intellisens tells me its outdated. How do i stop/start a thread?

Comment: How does the thread "take" the username and password? How do you start the thread? Could you *not* start the thread?

Comment: More interestingly, is why you are spawning a thread to do this...

Comment: Can you show the code that you have so far? That will perhaps make it more clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: @Jason94 why don't you work with events? A thread sounds like a sure overkill.. For example whenever one of the fields get focus lost, check if they are not empty and then validate them..

Comment: If you're using .NET 4.0, then you can use the Task Parallel Library. It's a great layer of abstraction for multi-threading.  Unless you're looking for a fine level of control, I suggest you look at that, here's a URL to get you started, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx

Comment: why don't you validate the inputs before running the thread ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see why you need a thread to get the input, but you should stop a thread by returning from it whenever the job is done. You should not just kill it.

```
if(!validInput(username, password))
    return;  // et voila
```

Edit: If your trying to synchronize more threads (like suspend/resume or wait/notify in java), then this information from the msdn may be useful:

> Thread.Suspend has been deprecated. 
>   Please use other classes in
>   System.Threading, such as Monitor,
>   Mutex, Event, and Semaphore, to
>   synchronize Threads or protect
>   resources. 
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=14202

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Thread.Abort()` method, but it can lead to inconsistent shared state due to terminating a thread violently. A better alternative is to use collaborative termination by using a `CancellationToken`.

```
// Create a source on the manager side
var source = new CancellationTokenSource();
var token = source.Token;

var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
  // Give the token to the worker thread.
  // The worker thread can check if the token has been cancelled
  if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
    return;

  // Not cancelled, do work
  ...
});

// On the manager thread, you can cancel the worker thread by cancelling the source
source.Cancel();
```

Comment: Thats why he mentions it @steve